Is there a PowerShell command to get Azure Databricks workspace URL
I'm trying to create a script where it need user and group details from Databricks workspace and to attain this I need to run the PowerShell script which will fetch databricks details from portal along with workspace URL. Is there a PowerShell command to my requirement where it can retrieve the workspace URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workspace/workspace-details

This question does not show any research effort ....

and, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.databricks/get-azdatabricksworkspace?view=azps-11.6.0

You can use below PowerShell script to get databricks workspace URL:
$resourceGroupName = "<resourceGroupName>"
$workspaceName = "<databricksWorkspaceName>"
$subscriptionId = "<subscriptionId>"

Connect-AzAccount
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$workspace = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces" -Name $workspaceName -ApiVersion "2018-04-01"
$workspaceUrl = $workspace.Properties.workspaceUrl
Write-Output "Databricks Workspace URL: $workspaceUrl"

It will retrieve the data bricks workspace URL successfully as shown below:

